# como exibir a primeira linha de um trecho de texto, fazendo link deste para a página onde ele está?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Preciso exibir a primeira linha do texto que estará entre o `[shortcode]` e que esta linha seja um link para a sua página de origem.

O código abaixo funciona, ele exibe uma div, mas eu quero exibir a primeira linha do texto que eu colocar `[shortcode]`entre`[/shortcode]`.

Para explicar a utilidade:

Estou usando o wordpress e preciso escrever pequenas notícias/textos em posts, onde a primeira linha de cada notícia, irá para determinados campos dentro de currículos (que são também posts).

Não encontrei nenhum plugin que consegue realizar isto com esta simplicidade.

```
<?php

add_shortcode('noticiaclaudio', 'func_news');
function func_news($atts, $content='') {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'height' => '15px',
        'width' => '60%',
        'padding' => '3px',
        'font-color' => '#999999',
        'font-size' => '12px',
        ), $atts));
    return '<div style="height:'.$height.';width:'.$width.';padding:'.$padding.';">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Primeira linha, como assim? Pode dar um exemplo real?

Comment: http://easfutebol.com.br/?p=180
A página acima é um dos currículuns onde preciso que seja inserida a primeira linha de notícias sobre o profissional, terei vários curricunluns, e preciso de editar um post com vávias notícias, mas que ao colocá-los dentro de determinado [shortcode], este insira a primeira linha lá naquele campo. Obrigada

Comment: Patricia, particularmente, não consigo visualizar seu problema. O link pro seu site é legal como referência, mas a descrição do problema (e código relevante) deve estar **todo dentro da pergunta**. Você é livre para editá-la sempre que precisar esclarecer/acrescentar-detalhes.

Comment: Se a resposta do KhaosDr não resolve o problema é porque ele não conseguiu interpretar/entender a pergunta. Seu trabalho é deixar o texto o mais claro possível (usando imagens, código, explicações, links). Isso permite respostas exatas e sem perda de tempo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção, como estou trabalhando com wordpress, encontrei um plugin que me facilitou a vida, se alguém precisar, segue o plugin: [https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcoder/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcoder/)

Answer (score 1):

Uma saída seria você utilizar o php para remover as tags shortcode, usando a seguinte função:

```
$a= '[shortcode]Hello World[/shortcode]';
echo str_replace("[shortcode]","",str_replace("[/shortcode]","",$a));
```

Isto retornaria

```
Hello World
```

Se você tivesse um texto com mais de uma linha, você poderia quebrá-lo em um array utilizando a função strtok, como dito [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097682/obtain-first-line-of-a-string-in-php) (e também comentado [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtok.php)) para pegar a primeira linha como:

```
$a = strtok($a, '\n')
```

Onde $a seria a primeira linha do seu texto.

Você poderia também utilizar um array no método:

```
<?php
 $lines=explode("\n", $string);
 echo $lines['0'];
?>
```

Que o resultado seria ainda a primeira linha do arquivo.